# Can consumer web part cause a refresh of provider web part?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a provider web part which has a gridview ot items, sorted by a Y/N status indicator and case number.  Click on the "select" link and the case number is passed to consumer web part which shows the details of that case.  User enters a claim number and clicks "set  status", which updates a table in DB for that case.  At that time I need the gridview in the provider to refresh itself by calling stored proc and re-populating grid view,reflecting the changed status of the item we just set status on.  Is there anyway to cause the provider to post back or refresh its gridview from the consumer web part?

thanks,,
Phil J.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this with a delegate.

The idea would be to create a delegate in your consumer web part, the provider would instantiate that delegate and when the consumer is finished, call the delegate. It may sound complicated if you never dealt with delegates, but it's actually quite an elegant solution.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), for how to create the delegate.

As a principle for good design, the child shouldn't call the parent. That's where the delegate comes in. The child exposes a delegate, the parent subscribes to that delegate by saying "when you're finished, notify me", and the child just calls the delegate, which fires a method in the parent.

Comment: Interesting, but I am a bit clueless without seeing the use of delegates in web parts to get my brain around the idea..